# Redireccionar un dominio a no-ip

Tags: iis, servidor, dns, dominio

Tengo un servidor con windows server 2008 en el cual tengo ligada una dirección no-ip, porque no tengo ip fija, contraté un dominio y ahora requiero redireccionar ese dominio a mi dirección de no-ip, tengo entendido que configuando los host records se soluciona, pero no me ha funcionado, tal vez no lo hago de la manera correcta.

En el administador de dominio, me aparecen 3 opciones, una con "*", otra con "@" y una más con "www", en las 3 opciones pongo la url de no-ip de tipo cname, pero en lugar de mostarme la página que debería, la de no-ip, me muestra el iis del servidor. Espero haberme explicado

¿Que configuración debería poner para que funcione correctamente?

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Si te muestra el IIS del servidor, entonces está bien configurado porque accedes al server, sin embargo para que se visualice correctamente el sitio debes trabajar en tu servidor:

Ahora hagamos que todo el tráfico que ingrese a tu URL vaya directo a la ruta donde tienes tu proyecto, para ello necesitas lo siguiente:

1-Haga un clic derecho sobre la carpeta ‘Sitios’ y seleccione ‘Agregar Nuevo Sitio’.

2-Dé un nombre al sitio – Por lo general yo le doy el nombre de dominio, aunque usted puede escoger el que desee, por ejemplo: mytestsite.com.

3.A continuación, tendrá que asignarle al sitio una ruta de acceso física a la carpeta en la computadora con el fin de alojar los archivos del sitio. Por lo general, siempre se guarda la carpeta en el archivo InetPub bajo el directorio wwwroot, es decir: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mytestsite.com.
De este modo puedo conservar todos mis sitios alojados en una sola carpeta bajo el nombre de dominio del sitio.

4-Por último, tendrá que asignar un nombre de host. Esta es la parte que puede confundir a la gente. Los nombres de host son aquéllos que IIS utiliza para enlazar los pedidos entrantes a los archivos físicos reales del sitio. Por ejemplo, si usted hace una solicitud de mysite.com, tan pronto como el sitio llega al servidor, pasa al Host Name, que IIS utiliza para buscar los archivos apropiados en el servidor. Usted debe tener un hostname configurado para mysite.com y también para www.mytestsite.com. Se trata de un olvido frecuente y luego la gente se pregunta por qué la versión www del sitio no funciona. También debe tener en cuenta que los nombres de host son únicos, no se puede tener dos sitios con los mismos nombres de host en un solo servidor.

5- Después de haber configurado estos parámetros, ya estará listo para iniciar el Sitio y seleccionar OK. A continuación verá una captura de pantalla que ilustra mi propia configuración:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Referencia: http://blog.iweb.com/es/2011/01/como-configurar-un-sitio-web-basico-en-iis/873.html